# Can I keep the baffle filter outside of septic tank

Tags: bathroom, toilet, septic, filter

My builder has made a mistake , he didn't install Baffle filter either for septic tank inlet or outlet and he didn't make any provision for soak pit or cess pit

[image]

Builder has kept both inlet pipes and outlet pipe in same horizontal level and on the same wall right next to one another.

[image]

There is a removable concrete slab but he has laid tiles all above septic tank because there's a bathroom above it.

[image]

if you see the below building diagram you will see septic tank lies underneath the building structure in south east corner

[image]

[image]

- Whenever the septic tank cleaner come , they open the outlet cap and suck the septic tank dry.
- The problem is there's no man hole to the septic tank as well , the only way is the outlet pipe. I agree builders made a big blunder, but I have to deal with this now.
- I'm improving the system i.e I have dug some cesspool near by septic tank so this pool helps with water percolation.
- Without baffle filter , cesspool will get filled up with scum and eventually fail.

[image]

- I'm gonna equip my septic system with commercial effluent filter so only the water escapes
- The problem is I can't place the effluent filter inside the septic tank without destroying the tiles in bathroom floor and I can't employ septic tank trucks if there's a Effluent filter inside the outlet cap.

[image]

- So Can I connect the effluent filter to the septic outlet from outside of the building and pass the filtered water to cesspool.
- But I have a feeling that this might fail as there's nothing to block the scum and also inlet and outlet of septic is on same level.

Any ideas are welcome to filter the septic tank

FYI:

- The area where the building situated has clay
- The water table is high like just 1 feet down from ground level in rainy season and 3 feet down from ground level in summer season.
- I'm confident the effluent filter works but it's just that I couldn't place it inside of the septic tank .. that's the problem
- Please see the cess pool and side of my building which has septic tank under neath
- I'm worried that there's a tremendous water pressure and positive air pressure building up in the septic tank which might cause issue with septic tank PVC lines,smelly toilets, weakening the foundation of south east side of the building

So I have to fix this issue